# "Serial upvoting reversed" makes reputation suspect for employers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, serial-voting, stack-overflow-jobs, reputation-history

Recently, I mentioned my Stack Overflow reputation points to a potential employer, although I didn't send them the link to my profile yet.

Apparently, two days ago, someone (I have no idea who or why) serial upvoted my posts, and yesterday it was reversed. Now my reputation points screen has a red, publicly-visible "serial upvoting reversed -80", and I think it makes the rest of my reputation points look suspect.

Obviously, someone who *did* try to game the system would deserve the scarlet letter. I have no idea how to establish that I don't know anything about the serial upvoting -- I was in top 4% for quarter with over 400 reputation points before the upvoting, since creating this account less than a month ago (I abandoned my previous account when I was a beginner years ago), so I didn't need the 80 points.

Is there any way to establish or just affirm that I don't know anything about the serial upvoting and have the red -80 not displayed? I know Stack Overflow is promoting using the site to show off to employers, and this makes me extremely reluctant to mention my Stack Overflow reputation points to a potential employer.

EDIT: To be clear, I don't care about the number, don't want the points restored, and don't think it's "all" that potential employers look at on Stack Overflow. I am concerned someone browsing my profile will think the "serial upvoting reversed -80" is because *I* tried to juice my own score and got caught. This is what looks bad.

As @Michael Geary notes, the "learn more" link leads to a page where it says the reversal is because of voting fraud, **voting fraud** is emboldened, yet in finer print it says that users are docked points after being *victims* of voting fraud -- a very counter-intuitive idea. Knowing users can be docked points due to other users' actions with which they had nothing to do is counter-intuitive and not at all automatic.

EDIT 2: Added feature-request tag per BoltClock's suggestion, "Perhaps it [Serial upvoting reversed] should only be made visible to moderators and the user themselves. It's not like this information is useful to anyone else except for public shaming anyway."

Comment: Perhaps it should only be made visible to moderators and the user themselves. It's not like this information is useful to anyone else except for public shaming anyway. Not sure if a case would have to be made for hiding serial downvote reversals as well, though - having something that's almost invariably an injustice against you written off is something quite different.

Comment: Well, it is quite visible how this happened.  User @B.S. was very happy with your answer and decided you deserved more than a single vote.  Creating happiness is nothing to be ashamed of, just point it out if they inquire.

Comment: Hmm, It's arguable at all if SO rep is a real good reference for any _potential employer_. (at least at this rep stage you are). Note: I don't want to sound arrogant, but 433 isn't that significant (yet).

Comment: If you look at the voting the day before that looks like serial up-voting to me.  I guess it was not caught by the algorithm

Comment: I've been serial upvoted a few times now.  The first one was quite shocking, but my take on it now is just that I helped a noob and s/he simply chose an inappropriate way to say thank you.  Dont let it ruffle your feathers.  Spin it as you have fans on SO. :)

Comment: Wow, I just clicked on the [(learn more)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) link next to your "serial upvoting reversed" note. That page is about the most tone-deaf thing I have read today (second only to Lenovo's comments about their SuperFish scandal). Does StackExchange realize that they have accused someone of **fraud** (it's even bolded!) who very likely had completely innocent intentions? Maybe they are an iOS developer who truly found your other answers helpful. Fraud is a very serious charge, and I would not take it lightly if it were directed at me.

Comment: Remember we're talking about *voting* fraud in imaginary internet points.  They have no value and as @πάνταῥεῖ says.. especially at your level.

Comment: And adding injury to insult, putting that bolded comment about **voting fraud** will do little to comfort your potential employer who follows that link in the hope of learning why your reputation plummeted. That page needs a serious rewrite that is *respectful* to all parties concerned.

Comment: These are not "imaginary internet points". We are talking about a situation where a potential employer may look at your SO profile, see something suspicious, and be led to a page where the most prominent words are **voting fraud**. That may well cause *real* loss of reputation in the *real* world.

Comment: @MichaelGeary _"That page needs a very serious rewrite that is respectful to all parties concerned."_ Why? Either a potential employer is aware of how the SO engine works (and look after in depth, and pretty well know what it means in that context), or they won't even give a shit at all (even I wouldn't give a shit about it when an apprentice would try to refer here, and I'm a bit of enlightened).

Comment: @MichaelGeary, I disagree.  Any employer that is hiring a developer based on the points a candidate has on SO is beyond crazy.  I might have gleaned all my points from "hey this is a null reference" posts.  Its looking at the posts and using that to evaluate, hopefully in addition to MANY other points.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for calling out the mention of "fraud" specifically, that is a big concern. About who or why upvoted, again I can only assert I have no idea who or why, but my first thought it was someone who liked many of my lengthy answers on this tricky, hard-to-get-information about part of iOS development-- that was what I originally hoped would happen, but since that can trigger this warning, now I hope it doesn't. Definitely some of these people I'm answering don't know how SO works.

Comment: @paqogomez: It's not the point numbers that are the issue here. It's the flippant use of "fraud" in a situation where it's very likely that no fraud was committed or intended. False accusations are never a good thing.

Comment: But it is possible that it *is* voting fraud.  Creating puppet accounts to upvote yourself happens all the time.  Hence the need for a reversal.  No one is suggesting that OP did this.  It can happen innocently as well.  What other would would you give it?

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ Of course 433 is not very impressive, but over 26 days, not bad. Anyway it's just a starter. Also see: @paqogomez  Please understand what my complaint is. I don't care about the points or want them restored. I don't anyone hires on the basis of the number. I am concerned someone could see the "serial upvoting reversed" and think I was docked points because I got caught trying to cheat to get more "fake internet points", thinking I wanted to juice my number to impress people-- which I think you would agree would be a huge black mark against someone.

Comment: I doubt potential employers would look at reputation change history - it's just numbers, and by themselves, not very interesting ones. Employers should be looking at the tags you are active in, the quality of your communication, and the depth of your understanding.

Comment: That is exactly my point.  It is not an huge black mark against you.  It happens, its well and easily explained.  Being this concerned about it suggests that you are perhaps not confident enough in explaining your skills to an employer.  @halfer has hit the nail on the head.  If anything *posts* matter, not points.

Comment: @paqogomez: Yes, it's *possible* that serial upvotes are "voting fraud". But they may often not be. Yet the help page labels totally innocent upvotes as fraud along with truly fraudulent behavior. Anyone who doesn't see the problem here should read up on [what the word fraud means](https://www.google.com/search?q=fraud).

Comment: @MichaelGeary so what alternatives do you have?  Perhaps this is an [English.SO](http://english.stackexchange.com/) question.

Comment: I've been serially up and downvoted a couple of times, and I can't say I've given it much thought. I''ve happily put my SO profile on my CV, and I'm pretty sure employers looking at it have not pounced on my reputation history changes, nor thought of me as a "fraud". Mountain, molehill (imo) `:-)`.

Comment: @paqogomez: Very good point! I should put my money where my mouth is. :-) So when I get a little time I will write up a more friendly draft of that help page. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: Not to sound rude, but I don't see what reporting SO reputation of just 533 to a potential employer is going to accomplish.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See my edit--I don't care about the point total. I care someone looking at my profile could reasonably conclude I cared about the number so much I tried to sockpuppet upvote myself.

Comment: @MichaelSand: Clearly you do, based on your opening words: _"Recently I mentioned my Stack Overflow reputation to a potential employer"_. I wouldn't have done that with just 533 rep. Heck, I feel dirty pretending that even 143,000 rep is an indication of anything at all, when discussing it with a recruiter.

Comment: Can't think of a good reason why a correction in rep should be displayed on the victim's profile. (Assuming they weren't complicit). I would hope an employer wouldn't rate points over content too.

Comment: Definitely should not show that in the history at all, except for the logged in user or the mods.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  Maybe I should have said originally "I recently mentioned that I got 330 points *in two weeks*" and in my edit/last comment "I don't care about *what the reversals did to* my point totals." Regardless, I can confidently mention my meager point total to potential employers because I do think it means something: Most of it was not low-hanging fruit, but questions in newer, tricky areas of iOS development. It's because I want people to poke around my profile and see how I earned it that its bothersome they could reasonably think fraud was involved or attempted.

Comment: @HansPassant the problem is that if they see this while doing initial checks on you, you may be disqualified before you even get the chance to explain. I'd be worried too.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I've had a couple of potential employers reach out based on my participation in StackOverflow. I can't say how deeply they looked into my profile, but it would be a mistake to assume they aren't looking or it doesn't matter.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Enough with the comparing point totals, please? Instead, take a look at [Michael's actual answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4474705/michael-sand?tab=answers). These answers not only demonstrate knowledge of some difficult topics in iOS development, but the ability to communicate well and and the desire to help other developers. Any prospective employer should be impressed, whether the author's point total is 400 or 400,000.

Comment: BTW, I am certain that I have committed "voting fraud" on more than one occasion. I start a project and am learning some new area, and a search leads me to a helpful answer to something I'm having trouble with. Out of curiosity I click the author's profile and see their other answers. Several of them also relate to the area I'm starting out in and are helping me learn about it, so I upvote them too!

Comment: @MichaelGeary: Yes, exactly. The OP should have pointed out his _posts_ to the employer, not his reputation. I'm not the one who made the choice to point out point totals!!

Comment: Well of course none of us were in on that conversation, were we? :-) How do we know that it wasn't something like this: "My SO rep is about 600. That's not a lot, but I've only been on there for a month. I try to write solid answers that explain tricky problems clearly, and people seem to appreciate them so far. I'll send you the link so you can look through the answers yourself."

Comment: I feel the issue here is that we can't necessarily assume that the most-apt member of a company (or recruitment firm) is going to be doing the one screening the initial candidates.

If the CTO has enough time, personally, to peruse each profile (of every applicant, not the screened ones), that's not likely a CTO I'd want.

If an HR or contract recruiter or junior dev was doing initial screening of *all* resumes, which included SO profile links, a "-400" bulk decrease and *FRAUD* in my recent-history might mean I never get the chance to be read by the right person, like the other candidates.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Thanks for the comments, and the conversation went exactly. like. that. Except then it was more around 300. Saying "I mentioned" didn't mean to imply I *only* mentioned the number. 'I got 300 points, wadda ya think about that?' Anyway, while the original question may have been oversimplified, I've clarified enough and my first edit was actually *before* @ LightnessRacesInOrbit started commenting (can only @ one person). And I'd probably be jaded if I had 140,000+ but people in the real world people are impressed by getting any amount of points answering questions on SO at all.

Comment: Does anyone want to work for an employer who reads SO to get a feel for what a candidate is like, but who doesn't understand how to read SO to get a feel for what a candidate is like?  Just imagine if you got the job, then got unfairly blamed for causing a problem, and you had to explain something complicated to them; what chance do you have if they can't even get something this easy to understand right!

Comment: @Poldie I wouldn't mind working for them, unless that was the view of the hiring department, and more aptly, my superiors.  In a big enough company, the person doing the hiring **is not the person reading the SO profiles**.  I know that I've been passed over multiple times, due to the writing style I employ in my SO / LinkedIn profiles. I've also been contacted directly, because of them.  The people trying to contact me aren't the CTO, the COO or the CEO; they're HR employees or recruitment agents or junior devs/co-ops screening dozens of people. My actual competency is measured *after* I pass

Comment: Wow... this is an upsetting question. I sit here stunned at the realization that I may have been guilty of infractions that, while innocent in intention, may have harmed people I intended to support! I've learned *so much* here on SO, and when I find a well written and helpful answer, I immediately search out other answers by this same guru. If the answers are helpful/illuminating to me, I will upvote them. It never occurred to me that might be a problem. **Suggestion: SO should detect this behaviour and pop-up an advisory note.** Bad idea to criminalize innocent and understandable behavior.

Comment: @MichaelSand - On the bright side, your profile page logged up a lot of recent views although I don't know how that would benefit you in a job application. Perhaps it will be taken as an indicator that you have an affable social presence.

Comment: For us culturally challenged: What is "the scarlet letter" (in this context)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Perhaps it's referring to the fact that [such a branding](http://www.amazon.com/Scarlet-Letter-Dover-Thrift-Editions/dp/0486280489/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1424531128&sr=8-1&keywords=the+scarlet+letter) is permanent.

Comment: @PeterMortensen check out the [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Scarlet_Letter) for a synopsis. Essentially, in very early colonial America (17th century), a woman is accused of adultery and forced to wear a scarlet (bright red) letter "A" branding her as such, so even people who have no idea who she is or the circumstances behind her actions will judge her as a "sinner."

Answer (score 43, accepted):

We can't hide these entirely, but the text for reverted votes is now a more ambiguous "Voting corrected" rather than directly implying a specific cause:

[image: Voting corrected]

The linked [Help Center page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) has also been revised with a more neutral tone.

Answer (score 83):

First off, if you're gonna send a link to your profile to a potential employer, make sure you tell 'em to read your *posts*. And if they don't, be very worried.

If they do visit your rep history & comment on the entry, make sure they've read [the help center topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) discussing it. Specifically, the last paragraph:

> #### Should I be concerned about reversal statements on my profile?
>
> No, not at all. It's only an indication of reputation change. After all, we can't control the actions of other users. It's very rare where we'd run across a user who was committing the voting fraud themselves on their own account, and in most instances of that, they will have already been dealt with accordingly. You should in no way be concerned with reversal statements in your reputation history.

Granted, if your rep history is *mostly* reversals (and mostly *not* votes) then that would be pretty damning - I probably wouldn't be showing such a profile to most employers. But that's not the case for yours.

#### See also: [Please hide "serial upvoting reversed" entries in the public reputation history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139080/please-hide-serial-upvoting-reversed-entries-in-the-public-reputation-history)

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. Very disappointing that this was brought to their attention in 2012, with 48 upvotes, and not acted upon. 

In this particular case the person I mentioned it to is technical, and I specifically mentioned my posts, most being in a tricky subfield. 

But a primary benefit of having a numeric score is it's shorthand; having to explain why your account was docked points ruins that benefit. Worse, I'm not sure when/where to mention this: Preemptively? The fact an explanation is needed means saying we should be concerned "No, not at all." is not correct.

Comment: I'd quite honestly forgotten about it. If folks still support this, it should be trivial to hide it; I'll make a note to follow up.

Comment: Thanks- actually the comment I made about 2012 isn't fair, because personally I wouldn't care at all, and the attitude in the FAQ statement would be fine-- except that since SO is now pushing this for employers, which is great, it could lead someone checking out a profile to jump to the conclusion someone is trying to game their rep.

Comment: I'd tend to agree with @Shog9 here. If that's all your potential employer looked at, then, maybe they might see you in a bad light, but honestly, I don't think any employer who would care enough to look you up on StackOverflow would only look at your reputation. One of the primary things that makes SO such a great tool for employers is you can actually get a glimpse at how the potential hire handles problems, writes code, etc. I doubt they care if your rep is 100 or 100,000. If your answers are good, that's all that will matter.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You have more faith than me in every person who might check my profile. Mentioning the number (and speed) has been useful already, at least as a starter, and now I'm reluctant to call it out specifically knowing there's a kind of asterisk attached to it. Ironically if someone looked only at the number it wouldn't be an issue. It is if they specifically asked "where did this reputation come from?" and clicked on the "reputation" tab to find out, and jump to conclusions. The idea that users can be docked points for reasons they had nothing to do with is not at all automatic.

Comment: Rep in general is a poor indicator of anything. Most of my rep came from a platform I haven't used now in over 2 years. The nature of SO is that you will typically answer questions from a wife range of tech. As someone who is responsible for hiring,  I would look at the user's answers specially related to the areas I'm hiring for.

Comment: @ChrisPratt but the person doing the hiring might not be the person doing the first-pass candidate screening (and given a technical/senior/corporate enough position, assuredly won't be). If a screener lands on your profile, and there in the "reputation" (a word that carries weight, elsewhere, even if it means little more than 'points earned', here) there's a gigantic -400 rep, yesterday, due to "click-fraud", that's a screener unlikely to think I have a "good reputation", even just at a gut-check level; akin to having a bad CV -- preemptively failed for the wrong reasons.

Comment: "And if they don't, be very worried." +1

Comment: If there is something looking like `-80` on someones profile with the statement of "serial voting", I would also suggest, a **serial voter** badge, maybe black in color, for those who have serially voted, and not dealt(profile not deleted) with yet

Comment: "If they do visit your rep history & comment on the entry, make sure they've read the help center topic discussing it. Specifically, the last paragraph"
-- But we can't make sure of that. We have no control over what they do and what faulty conclusions they jump to if they scan that page and see the bolded words **voting fraud**. They might not even bother to explain why you won't be called back for an interview.

Comment: @Shog9 I accepted this answer because of the comment about following up, especially since since it was made the feature-suggestion comment to hide the notice on the question has racked up upvotes. No promises on your part, of course, but great to hear it's going to be considered.

Comment: A comment that seems relevant to make: if I'm applying to Megatech Firm Inc, and I say look at what I'm doing on SO, I expect the recruiter to read what my answers are and discern my programming ability.  But if I'm applying to local non-tech small business who is hiring their first programmer I'll point them to my account here and expect my reputation to convince them that I can do basic python programming, because if they understood my answers they wouldn't be hiring a programmer.  If they instead see that I appear to be committing *voting fraud*, well no job for me.

Comment: @Joel You expect a recruiter to read code? That's not what recruiters are doing. At least not any of the ones I met. They don't evaluate candidates on a technical level. They scan resumes for experience and a few keywords, check candidate availability, and then forward the resume to the hiring manager. That's where the technical evaluation starts.

Comment: It is extremely unrealistic to educate future employers about Stack Overflow policies.

Comment: @Joel I've met, perhaps two recruiting firms who were boutique, high-priced, high-tech recruiters, such that they did their own technical interviews/assessments (atop of the typical "pre-job interview interview") prior to making suggestions to clients. The clients tended to be people like the parent company for AirMiles, or other internationals tied to loyalty or credit-lending... The rest of the recruiters I've talked with have been much less technical; still helpful, nice, discerning, even, but not technical. I can look at your "reputation" right now, and at a glance, I can tell, in general-

Comment: how helpful your answers are, in perpetuity. A recruiter who is non-technical, who has a stack of keywords and a job description, might look at that profile tab as a quick indicator of how helpful you've been, on a timeline, for things which might match those keywords. There are, in fact, no other pages which offer such a quick overview aside from your own handwritten profile, as far as a non-technical researcher goes... ...or even a technical resource who is now sifting through 23 potential candidates, while also doing their day job, and thus, can't rank each on the quality of their answers.

Answer (score 26):

If they implement [BoltClock's suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286494/serial-upvoting-reversed-makes-reputation-suspect-for-employers#comment157313_286494) that would solve the problem.

In the meantime, point anyone who thinks you did something wrong to ["What is serial voting and how does it affect me?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me). Specifically:

> #### Should I be concerned about reversal statements on my profile?
>
> No, not at all. It's only an indication of reputation change. After all, **we can't control the actions of other users.** It's very rare where we'd run across a user who was committing the voting fraud themselves on their own account, and in most instances of that, they will have already been dealt with accordingly. You should in no way be concerned with reversal statements in your reputation history.

Explain that the reversal is there because **someone else** did something they should not have. And you may also point out that it is possible for people to serial upvote someone else without realizing that this is what they are doing. Someone finds an answer that they like, click on the user profile, start reading other answers that they like and pretty soon they are serially voting. There's nothing evil going on here but the system sees it as undesirable.

An employer who does not get this, or who will eliminate a candidate without knowing that serial voting means is probably not someone you want to work for.

Comment: I absolutely agree with BoltClock's suggestion. 

The fact that we're talking about how you might explain this mark to potential employers and communicate to them "it's not what it looks like, I have no idea how this happened, please don't hold it against me" indicates  "No, not at all.... You should in no way be concerned with reversal statements in your reputation history" is outdated.

Comment: @MichaelSand maybe put that suggestion in as a feature request if you really like the suggestion.

Comment: It's not where you'd have no idea how it happened, and if you were unable to explain it, it might make you look dumb. You say someone voted on a bunch of posts they liked of yours, but the system reversed it because it *thought* there might have been something nefarious going on with *that person* - not you. I agree it can make it look like you hired someone to upvote you a lot and got caught, but would you be sharing your rep with employers if you did? I doubt it. But as another said, if the screener doesn't ask you about it if they see it, and skips you, they probably aren't worth your time.