# Serial Voter Notification Mechanism

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I have asked a [question with bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43298072/hibernate-objects-are-getting-saved-without-transaction-object) and it is not having any convincing answers till now and the bounty ended. However it gained attention after I offered bounty, somebody just read it, maybe found it useful and fell in love with my each and every question that I asked on Stackoverflow till now. And the next thing happened was...

[image]

However as you can see that the love story ended when the voting was reversed.
What I want to know is that, did Stack Overflow notify the serial upvoter that their voting was reversed and they are not allowed to do that again? Is there any notification mechanism for this to notify that user?

*Because they may be spreading the much-needed love, but may not be aware that doing so is not worth , unless they studied the website completely.*

Comment: Such a system is not in place afaik, but has been discussed before https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290177/should-we-notify-serial-upvoters

Comment: Any reason why do you relate your bounty to the user that upvotes your questions and answers?

Comment: Yea @justhalf , actually I am a bit sad that my points have been deducted and I haven't received any suitable answer, so my emotions spilled out along with the primary question.... #sadLoveStory