# Is a serial voter notified when serial voting is reversed if voting didn't cost reputation?

Tags: support, serial-voting, voting-correction

When user A serial-downvotes user B on answers and the reversal script catches it, both users recieve a reputation change (both positive) and a justification:

> +10   03:00   reversal    Voting corrected (learn more)

But if user A serial-downvotes only on user B questions (stealth downvotes) or serial-upvotes user B posts, when reversal occurs, user B is notified (with a gain or loss of rep depending on the vote, I was user B multiple times so I know).

But since I was never user A (and I'm not going to find out by experimenting), does user A get notified when the reversal doesn't change their reputation (upvotes/questions downvotes) ?

Related: [Should we notify serial upvoters?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290177/should-we-notify-serial-upvoters) but that question asks for a feature to notify upvoters *when they are performing the upvotes*. So not a duplicate *at all*.

Comment: I've never gotten a notification that serial upvoting was reversed against me (which has happened once or twice, IIRC)... I only got a notification that my reputation had changed.

Comment: hmmm let me check. Those elections got me a massive serial upvote, which was reversed. yes, mentions reversal: `-152  03:00  reversal  Voting corrected (learn more)`

Comment: I mean, the notification was made *because* there was a rep change. That they include the reason is unrelated.

Comment: iirc there is no sort of automatism when serial votes get reverted. That means the only time you'll be notified will be if a mod writes a mod message to you, which iirc they only do as warnings. So if it aint your fault, you'll probably not be notified.

Comment: yes, if there's no rep change, how are they going to tell the user that the voting was reversed?

Comment: @Magisch if you serial upvote someone it _is_ your fault. And you need to be warned to avoid to do it again.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre only if they make a habit of it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters but if reversal script doesn't notify anyone, how can mods detect that repeated behaviour? I'm tempted to edit my question adding "are the mods warned" but I don't want to chameleon you

Comment: No, mods are not warned. If you have received multiple serial votes feel free to raise a custom mod flag.

Comment: But it’s really not that prevalent or a problem. Most cases are isolated and people move on.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, if the voter didn’t see any reputation change from voting, then reversal will not result in a notification either.

See the [Uber-Meta FAQ on serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857):

> - **There is no automated punishment or notifications.**
>
>   Currently, the serial voting script *only* reverses the votes, and takes no other action except putting an event in your reputation history. There is no automated ban for users who engage in serial voting, and the only form of notification they receive that their votes were reversed is "+1 undownvote" events in their reputation history if they had downvoted answers (if they only downvoted questions or had only upvoted things, they will not be notified in any way).