# Unusual Voting Correction: -2033 Reputation Points

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, voting-correction

Recently, my account experienced a significant voting correction of -2033 reputation points, which could also be a mistake given its unusual magnitude. It stands out from the typical reputation drops ranging between -10 and -250 points due to user removals I've seen over the years, and it's the first time I've encountered such a substantial correction. It is also strange that initially -2014 points were corrected, followed by an additional -19. However, the phrase "voting corrected" and the [learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed) link provide no clarity.

[image]

I am aware this could be related to voting fraud<sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/426867/6574038),[2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371704/6574038)</sup> , yet I have not engaged in such activities. I don't boast about my contributions on this site, and I am not sure who would systematically upvote me. To my knowledge, no other user in my tags experienced the same.

While I expect to regain the lost reputation points promptly, understanding the cause of this correction is critical to maintaining credibility and upholding a professional reputation, especially for potential employers, reviewing my profile<sup>[3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/286494/6574038)</sup>.

Seeking insights on:

1. Identifying the specific votes corrected.
2. Uncovering what exactly triggered this correction - whether it was due to alleged voting fraud or other factors.
3. Any similar recent experiences within the community?
4. Proactive measures to prevent such incidents

Comment: Doesn't seem there is an indication that you were at fault. It's most likely some voting ring being eliminated and you were just one of the victims. Probably a large one. Don't think you can get clarity on 1. and as for 4. - I don't think you yourself can do anything to prevent voting rings and fraudulent voting of others.

Comment: @VLAZ TY for your comment. I've been thinking about unusual upvotes this year (since I dropped from top 0.07% to top 0.11% this year), but I think a massive number of 2033 would have caught my eye, though.

Comment: *"I am not sure who would upvote me 2033 times"* You're off by a factor of 10 (reputation per upvote), so it's 203.3 upvotes (give or take).  I...don't have a great explanation for those exact numbers, though.  Also, the upvotes were from multiple people. *"no other user in my tags experienced the same"* Some number of other users were also hit by this invalidation (and lost more reputation).

Comment: Just to clarify, that's not 2033 *upvotes*. It's score total, so it's a mix of upvotes, downvotes and maybe acceptances.

Comment: I've brought this post to the attention of the staff member who processed this invalidation; it's _possible_ there was an error (human judgement is involved), so I think it's good to double-check in this case.  Only staff members with access to individual vote data will be able to check for certain.

Comment: @RyanM Oh yes, thanks for pointing that out, I corrected it in OP. Thank you for bringing it to staff's attention. I fully understand and support correction of abuse. However, the respective votes should be corrected and not all deducted at once so that the [reputation curve buckles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426974/unusual-voting-correction-2033-reputation-points?noredirect=1#comment976538_426976). This should be discussed.

Comment: So if your real concern your reputation graph, @jay.sf ? Why? Much like reputation itself, it's just internet points.

Comment: @ThomA No, the curve reflects what technically happened―points were subtracted not votes corrected.

Comment: *"points were subtracted not votes corrected."* What does that even mean..? Votes *were* corrected. Votes result in reputation, and if they votes are reversed, so too is the reputation. The votes were corrected, and you *lost* reputation as a result.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406093/can-the-counter-on-the-reputation-tab-be-modified-to-reflect-the-net-change-in-r

Comment: @ThomA, I appreciate your input. My point is that while votes were corrected, the manner in which the reputation was subtracted all at once created a sudden dip in the reputation graph, which doesn't accurately reflect the historical voting pattern. It's more about accurately representing the voting history rather than the mere loss of reputation points. I believe a more staggered correction, reflecting when the votes actually occurred, would have been more representative and less abrupt on the reputation graph.

Comment: @jay.sf As far as I know, if an account is destroyed due to it being apart of a voting ring, then so are the votes.  Meaning they would never have occurred in the first place as far as tracking changes go.  Like deleting a revision record instead of just undoing the change made.

Comment: @Daedalus Yes, that's what I would expect, thanks. So I'm currently assuming it's an SE cache issue, as you explain in your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426974/unusual-voting-correction-2033-reputation-points?noredirect=1#comment976549_426976).

Comment: I know this is hard, but something similar happened to me a few years ago. Apparently a user who was a "fan" of mine had his account deleted (or was deleted) and in the process I lost all the reputation I got from him  (similar amount as yours). This sucks and doesn't seem to be a good solution for anyone involved.

Comment: So, reading between the many lines, this is actually a [[meta-tag:feature-request]], to ask that when a user's votes are reversed, that the reputation is removed from the targets gradually, rather than all at once. Is that correct? If so, you have my downvote.

Comment: @ThomA, thanks for the engagement. Daedalus pointed out that Stack Exchange might cache votes, which could result in a delay in flattening the curve. This suggests that the sudden drop in reputation could correct itself over time without a need for a new feature. My primary intent remains to understand the unusual voting correction, and this discussion has provided valuable insights towards that. I appreciate your input and the broader perspective.

Comment: @ThomA I understood it as a feature request that corrected votes are processed retroactively, i.e., the whole reputation history (and graph) recalculated as if the votes never happened. This would cause the reputation history to have a normal/more accurate slope (just ever so slightly less steep than it originally was with the fraudulent votes) instead of showing a sharp drop at a given moment. While this seems computationally prohibitive I actually don't think it is a bad idea.

Comment: That's more or less how it worked a long time ago, @Marijn - reputation would be recalculated and it would appear as though the votes never existed. The downside was that catching errors like this one was difficult; some folks used 3rd-party services to track their reputation just to have an accurate record.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A Community Manager reversed the invalidation. You'll note your reputation is back where it was. Unfortunately, with the recent staff shakeup, some new folks are learning the vote invalidation tools, [which have something of a learning curve apparently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408756/2370483), but thankfully, vote reversals can now be undone pretty easily.

Answer (score 6):

The correction isn't against you, it's against another user (or many). The votes by those users have been invalidated and, it appears, that many of those votes may have targetted you. This *might* have been to hide their actual true target(s).

To answer the bullet points:

1. You can't, the action, as I mentioned, is against users not posts.
2. You won't, that information won't be disclosed because it's got nothing to do with you. You weren't at fault, and moderators/CMs don't discuss actions against other users.
3. All the time. There was a very large such "event" on [23 June 2021](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408801/2029983).
4. There already are and many of these systems work well. What you are seeing is a reactive measure. That you are seeing a reactive measure doesn't mean there aren't proactive measures too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and also for the link you shared, the wording of which is appropriate for what happened (albeit a bit verbose). However, my reputation curve shows a bend at this point in time; therefore, the voting was not actually corrected, but 2033 was deducted from me, which is a small but fine difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, @jay.sf , the voting *was* corrected; the votes *someone else* made were revoked/invalidated. The correction is invalidating those votes as they were, apparently, illegitimate. I think you're reading the action as the correction is against you (or your reputation). As I stated "The correction isn't against you, it's against another user (or many)"

Comment: I mean, if the votes were really corrected, I wouldn't see more reputation than I currently have when I mouse over my reputation curve (plot) in my profile. So the votes were not corrected, it just looks like I got -2033 that day.

Comment: @jay.sf Have you considered caching?

Comment: [Should you blame caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) @jay.sf .

Comment: @Daedalus Yes thanks. Deleted cache and still shows > 60K a few days ago.

Comment: @jay.sf I didn't say anything about _your_ cache.  SE caches data too, you know.

Comment: @Daedalus Ah didn't know. So you mean the cache will be cleared? When?

Comment: @jay.sf I don't know.  That'd be a question for SE, but I'd recommend checking out [this post which speaks of a similar problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406093/can-the-counter-on-the-reputation-tab-be-modified-to-reflect-the-net-change-in-r).  I already linked this same post above on this question.

Comment: If we're talking about the graph, then hate to break it to you but yeah it would appear as a drop in the graph. (For example I have a voting correction for 180 rep on my graph sometime in February this year)

Comment: @jay.sf actually it is relatively easy to find out which votes have been corrected specifically (your question #1), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/312191/.

Comment: Even more easy if you use the app I wrote for that: https://se-reputation-audit.glitch.me/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I just got a VC (-50/-90) rep change.  The "link" states that it wasn't a fault of mine, but tbh,  reputation decreases has this 'connotation' that I did something wrong.  Yes, it's just a psychological thing, but, it's disconcerting that maybe I did do something wrong?

Comment: Again, you *didn't* do something wrong, @ewokx , someone else did and it impacted you. Their actions have been undone, and that has impacted you.